# mef or unity is a impretive choice for prism?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, prism, mef, autofac

Heading for alternative using for prism and di/ioc. mef is skilful framework for prism but not so fast. trying to use autofac for prism because our application infrastructure have to many presentation layer like a web, mobile, tablet(silverlight) and desktop(wpf). mef is not good idea for web(if there is no pluggin operation etc. requirements)

tried mef and autofac together. used aggregate catalog and exposed parts to autofac but it's a not complatetly solution. there is to many problems to be solved. using are together.(prism, prism.mefextensions, prism.autofacextensions and autofac's mefintegration)

using prism.autofacextensions for alternating mef but autofac is not ready to prism i think. tried some alternative projects but not ready. also autofac is not inject import attributed object automatically and not have a scanning tool for directory(export attribute scanner. it's must be coded.) and all prism extensibility must be declared. i think its not ready to use for prism.

is there a any alternative ready to use for prism framework? we must use ioc container for all presentation layers. whats best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, **Unity** container supports all the layers you mentioned of **ASP.NET Web API**, **Windows Phone 8**, **Silverlight** and **WPF**.

In addition, **Bootstrapper** implementation and any other feature related to **PRISM** becomes relatively simple to achieve as **PRISM** already includes the ***UnityBootstrapper*** class which implement most of the required functionality.

You can find helpful information for **Unity** container in the following **CodePlex Unity** site:

- [Microsoft Unity Container 3](https://unity.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Unity3ReleaseNotes)

I hope this helps.

Comment: After 2 years, thank you again. I think there is no simple answer for this. We choose castle windsor container and implemented a custom bootstrapper and all functionality is works. That is solved our problems and requirements. But the point is used container. Choose the best one for you.